# Best practices for Moneydance extension development

Tags: java, plugins, standards

Are there any best practices when developing [Java-based extensions for Moneydance](http://moneydance.com/developer)?

Comment: This sounds like a good question for the moneydance support/forum http://help.infinitekind.com/

Answer (score 3):

As the founder and main developer of Moneydance I can admit to using several different environments to write extension, from emacs+terminal+ant to Xcode, eclipse and (currently) IntelliJ's IDEA.

The only thing that I'd really recommend is to use ANT.  That is mainly because it makes my life easier when you submit an extension for review and to be signed.  The sample extension available from moneydance.com/developer also provides a sample ant build file.  Other than ANT, just use your favorite java environment.